# How to charge different amount and not actual authorize amount through stripe?

Tags: php, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment

I have used woocommerce stripe payment gateway for woocommerce to capture and process payment.

The order amount becomes authorize amount for later payment and not immediate capture through stripe when placing order. The order status becomes **'Hold'**.

But i want to send different amount to capture payment through stripe.
When i send different amount to capture payment then i am getting message like -

`This PaymentIntent's amount could not be updated because it has a status of requires_capture. You may only update the amount of a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses: requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_action.`

But when i am passing actual authorize order amount, then payment is successfully processed.

Actually, I am capturing user's payment details and charging $1. Then allowing him to use a consultation on phone service. When consultation completes, i want to charge based on number of minutes of the twilio phone call.

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe [Setup later payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session) and charge the $1 seperate.

Comment: Can you provide your code to clearly show what steps you're taking and when?

Comment: @CodeSpirit in 'Setup later payments' can i charge any amount or i have to fix that amount beforehand ?

Comment: What code have you written? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!